# Horizontal stack of legends in xmgrace figure

Tags: legend, xmgrace

Is it possible to have a horizontal stack of legends in xmgrace, e.g., two rows and 3 columns?

Comment: An screenshot or code snippet will greatly help you question.

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I know it's not possible. However, as it always happens with xmgrace, you can use some hacks to solve the issue. Let's say you have 6 datasets and you want to split the legend in 3 columns. In this case you can

- prepare your plot
- duplicate the graph 3 times
- in each graph you add the legend to 2 datasets
- arrange the 3 legends to your liking

You'll end up with something like this:

[image]